# how deep can .find go

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, find

I know I can use find easily like

```
answers.find(question => question.questionId === displayingQuestionId)
```

but my structure is:

```
answers: [
  {questionId: 0000,
   answers: [{title: 'answer1'},{title: 'answer2'}]
]
```

so how can I use find in this:

where I want to find the questionId that matches the questionId for the answers

I realise this is quite confusing

`answers.find(question => question.answers.questionId === displayingQuestionId)`

something like that ^ except that is not working...

Comment: The first one is appropriate for structure you have unless you want to match a property in one of the answers.answers or you haven't shown full depth of data

Comment: `find` is probably not the function for doing this because even though you can use a condition that checks inner arrays, it can only return an element from the top lever array.

Comment: "I want to find the questionId that matches the questionId for the answers" could you show an example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: Show the object you actually want to search. You showed an object with answers, but they only have title. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can get the property as deep as you want. But you can't just use question.answers.questionId for the correct comparison.
Obviously, each loop of .find will give you object of the top level. After you can do with this all you want.

Example:

```
let arr = [{'questionId': 0000, 'answers': [{'title': 'answer1'},{'title': 'answer2'}]}];

//returns object of the top level if questioned equals to 0

arr.find((answer) => answer.questionId === 0);

//comparison with the internal array elements
//returns answer if one of the internal answers has title 'answer 1'

arr.find((answer) => !!answer.answers.find((internalAnswer => internalAnswer.title === 'answer1')));
```